# what free percentage is good for a partition to maintain? This is only for SSDs NOT HDDs

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

This question was asked before in a general manner but the answers only focus on HDDs, which have specific reasons to why a percentage should left free. [what free percentage is good for a partition to maintain? [closed]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/590622/what-free-percentage-is-good-for-a-partition-to-maintain)

In my case, I just bought an M.2 SSD drive. It's not really big (250GB) compare to my data (450GB) which doesn't include the large files like movies, music and pictures, those are in a separate HDD.
So, I want to put as much as I can on my new SSD, specially what needs constantly reading. I will for sure install everything in the SSD (OS itself) including my Home directory, but some of its contents will have to be left out.
So, what porcentage should I leave free on the SSD. I've heard that performance doesn't change even when the SSD is 100% full, but I've heard some arguments against it. Also, would this affect the live of the SSD? How about any other problems that I haven't thought of?

Comment: How does this differ from the answer you've linked?  (I don't see a substantial enough difference between the two)

Comment: Every answer to that question is for HDDs, the accepted answer even mentions that its answer doesn't appy to SSDs because they're very different.  Quote: "SSDs are a totally different kind of animal, as are system partitions"

Comment: The second answer on there refers to SSD performance differences.  Life differences are variable from manufacturer to manufacturer.  Your comment refers explicitly to the one accepted answer, not all the other answers (judge by *all* answers, not just the accepted)

Comment: That was even addressed by my own question, where people do say that performance doesn't change on SSDs. How about the live of the SSDs? Will storing more data degrade it? Will write performance lower when drive is almost full? if so, at what porcentage? Those are just a few questions I have.  Saying that an SSD is better (any of the answer in the previous question) doesn't address my question at all. Do SSD have a limit? or should I go nuts and fill it to 100% capacity?

Comment: Maybe this answer here might give you more of an understanding of why you would want free space.  SSDs are mentioned.  http://www.howtogeek.com/215413/why-does-emptying-disk-space-speed-up-computers/